# Adding custom jquery plugin of twitter search api to Drupal

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to implement this jquery plugin into Drupal.  http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/20/latest-tweets-tooltip/

I added the following js into my theme.info and the required css.

```
scripts[] = js/jquery.twitter.search.js
scripts[] = js/jquery.twitterpopup.js
```

I called the plugin with the following

```
(function($) {
$('.article').find('.twitter_search').twitterpopup();
}(jQuery));
```

I am not sure what is wrong that the plugin is not working.  I hope someone can guide me through this.

HTML

```
<div class="article">
    <span class="twitter_search">experiment</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there an element of the `article` class in your page? Is there a `.twitter_search` element inside?

Comment: Or with other words: can you show us your html?

Comment: html added, I am using drupal 7 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you calling the plugin from? i.e. what file is your function in

Are you sure that your JS is actually running? Try just doing an alert or a console log to check that anything is happening, or use Firebug or Chrome dev tools to add in breakpoints.

One thing to check with Drupal is that you have refreshed the theme registry since adding your scripts to the theme.info file.

clear all caches, or visit the theme settings page.

Comment: Vote up for cache clearing tip. Usually solves most of my weird problems.

Comment: I put the function inside a file called jtweet.js and added it to theme.info as well.  Cleared my cache and all that.  I have three other custom jquery scripts that I wrote but they are working just fine.  Am I calling the function wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`(function($) {
$('.article').find('.twitter_search').twitterpopup();
})(jQuery);`

You had an error in syntax in `}(jQuery))` need to be `})(jQuery)`

Comment: so if your function just says `alert('hello world');` does the alert happen?
also if you use firebug etc, is your script on the page?
does the console show any errors?